# Conditional comment not working for a <link>

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, conditional-statements, comments

I have a a conditional comment in my page to fix a double padding-top problem with IE7.

I am trying to add "padding-top:5px;" to a DIV only in IE7.  The rest of the browsers (including IE6 and IE8) use "padding-top:10px;" contained in stylesheet.css.

stylesheet.css contains

```
.clImageSamplerText {padding-top:10px;}
```

stylesheet_ie7.css contains

```
.clImageSamplerText {padding-top:5px;}
```

If I use

```
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <style>.clImageSamplerText {padding-top:5px;}</style>
<![endif]-->
```

my code works no problem.

If I use

```
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="stylesheet_ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

it does not work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark -- if you are using an XHTML doctype, you might find that closing your `<link />` tags will fix the problem.

So try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet_ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I have included `link` elements in conditional comments without any problems before, so I don't think it matters that you do that instead of writing it out in a `style` element. My best guess is that the document is not finding `stylesheet_ie7.css`. Are you sure it got uploaded to the right place?